# Usage of SpringXD Mail Source with named channels

Tags: java, spring, email, spring-batch, spring-xd

when I create a stream and use the [HelloSpringXDTasklet example Job](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/blob/master/src/docs/asciidoc/Creating-a-Job-Module.asciidoc) like this: `stream create email-stream --definition "mail ... > queue:job:helloSpringXD"`

I always get an exception:

```
2016-05-24T10:42:29+0200 1.3.1.RELEASE ERROR task-scheduler-5 handler.LoggingHandler - org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformationExceptio
n: Failed to transform Message; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentExcepti
on: Unable to convert provided JSON to Map<String, Object>
        at org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler.handleRequestMessage(MessageTransformingHandler.java:95)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:99)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:147)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:120)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:442)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:392)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:231)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:154)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:102)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:105)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.PollingConsumer.handleMessage(PollingConsumer.java:103)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:251)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.access$000(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:57)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:176)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:173)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:330)
        at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)
        at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
        at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:51)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:324)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to convert provided JSON to Ma
p<String, Object>
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:96)
        at org.springframework.integration.transformer.AbstractMessageProcessingTransformer.transform(AbstractMessageProcessingTransformer.java:90)
        at org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler.handleRequestMessage(MessageTransformingHandler.java:89)
        ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to convert provided JSON to Map<String, Object>
        at org.springframework.xd.dirt.plugins.job.ExpandedJobParametersConverter.getJobParametersForJsonString(ExpandedJobParametersConverter.java:169)
        at org.springframework.xd.dirt.plugins.job.JobLaunchRequestTransformer.toJobLaunchRequest(JobLaunchRequestTransformer.java:128)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodExecutor.java:113)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:102)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.access$000(MethodReference.java:49)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference$MethodValueRef.getValue(MethodReference.java:347)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:88)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:131)
        at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:330)
        at org.springframework.integration.util.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.evaluateExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:166)
        at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.processInternal(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:317)
        at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.process(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:155)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:93)
        ... 37 more
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'This': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@4135c5a7; line: 1, column: 5]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1419)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:508)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._reportInvalidToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:2300)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._handleOddValue(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:1459)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.nextToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:683)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:3105)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3051)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2175)
        at org.springframework.xd.dirt.plugins.job.ExpandedJobParametersConverter.getJobParametersForJsonString(ExpandedJobParametersConverter.java:166)
        ... 53 more
```

My `job-definition.xml`:

```
<bean id="helloSpringXDTasklet"
      class="org.springframework.springxd.samples.batch.HelloSpringXDTasklet" />

<batch:job id="EmailImporterJob">
    <batch:step id="helloSpringXDStep" next="process-step">
        <batch:tasklet ref="helloSpringXDTasklet" />
    </batch:step>
    <batch:step id="process-step">
        <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:chunk reader="itemReader" processor="itemProcessor" writer="itemWriter" commit-interval="10" />
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

However, as the Job should print **Hello Spring XD!** to the log, but the exception is thrown before that, I'm wondering which `JSON` and which `Map<String, Object>` is meant in the error message.

Is there a proper way to use the mail source with named channels?

Answer (score 0):

The named channel here in this batch job is the incoming channel that expects the job launching request from source module. So, in this case the output of the `Mail` source is considered to be the job launching parameter for your batch job.

Since the payload from `Mail` source is of type `String`, the job parameter converter assumes it as `JSONString` and tries to convert to `Map` to use it as a job parameter.

Comment: Is there any way to define, that the job takes the `String` and does not try to convert it to a `Map`?